# SQL Server 2008 R2 64bit Management Studion - Intellisense not working on Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, intellisense, ssms

I've tried several suggestions online including [all the ones mentioned here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/) for SQL Server 2012. But Intellisense still does not work. What else can I try?

I have SP3 for SQL Server 2008 R2 64bit installed. I also have Visual Studio 2010, 2012, and 2013 installed with latest Service packs and updates. I reinstalled SP1 for VS2010 (as suggested by some) but still no luck.

Comment: First, have you tried restarting SSMS after setting the intellisnese options?  IIRC, that is often necessary.  Secondly, make sure that your SSMS version and the version of SQL Server that you are connecting to *are the same version*.  Aaron doesn't mention it in the linked article (though he does talk about how it won't work with SS2005), but in my experience, SSMS intellisense does not seem to interoperate across versions *at all*.  In other words, SSMS 2012 does not provide intellisense for SQL Server 2008, etc.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, the restart of the SSMS did not help either. The SQL Server version info is: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64). The SSMS version is: 10.50.16.17.0. How can I upgrade the SSMS to the same version?  I checked the SSMS version using the help from: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185.

Comment: those are both version 2008 R2 so it should be OK.  At this point, I have no idea.  You may need to elevate it with Microsoft.

Comment: Do you have a 3rd party tool installed? I had RedGate's SQL tools installed and it messed with intellisense after the trial ran out. Try removing any 3rd party tools you might be using in conjunction with SSMS.

Comment: @GVashist, I do not have any 3rd party tools installed.

Comment: Did you take a look at this? [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531482)

Comment: @GVashist, yes, as mentioned in my original post, I did reinstall SP1 for VS2010. The Microsoft KB you referenced also talks about CU 7. But since I've SP3 of SQL Server installed, it includes CU7 and beyond.